# Split Container of data in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, split

I have an application that i have built, these servers send data back and forth, the master server i have setup gives me the messages in this format.

```
{ 'register 9f624ed': '' }
```

I would like to be able to split this key into different sections.
I have used the .split method, this doesn't seem to work for this purpose, i get all sorts of errors.

I would like to be able to cut off { ' 
leave me register in a variable
and then leave me 9f624ed in a variable.

Thanks for any advice anyone can offer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` to obtain the keys on the object and then use `.split()` on one of the keys.  Here's working code in a snippet:

```js
var data = { 'register 9f624ed': '' };
var keys = Object.keys(data);
var splits = keys[0].split(" ");

// show output in snippet window
document.write(JSON.stringify(splits));
```